# Jmeter error due to captured token containing '\x'

Tags: jmeter, token

In my testing scenario most of the responses fail due to the captured token having a \x in it.
The token without this \x does pass. How should I handle this token or what is required to be converted here.
I did try urlencode , urldecode

token for example - 00ceR2t8n\x2DfSp6lfvPvm_xxB23683omTcxbE\x2DulsTf

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to remove these `\x` signs the best option is going for [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) like:

```
${__strReplace(${token},\\\x,,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

`__strReplace()` function can be installed as a part of **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSR 223 post processor and write the code below:

```
def responseToken = vars.get("token")
def newToken = responseToken.replace("\\x", "")
vars.put("newToken", newToken)
```

Then use this newToken variable

Answer (score 0):

Probably my question was not constructed the right way.

The below solution worked for me -

added a beanshell postprocessor with the below code

**${__javaScript("${stateToken}".split('\x2D').join('-'),FOO)}**
the converted variabled was stored in Foo.

and substituted ${Foo} in the the required place.